# SFTP connection issue with password

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ftp, sftp

I am running this script to copy pattern files in local but it is asking for password even passing the hardcode value.

Script:

```
PASSWORD="xyz"

sftp -oport=1002 user@host:/dir/archive/file*.txt /di/data/
<< EOF

$PASSWORD

quit

EOF
```

Got error:

```
-bash-4.1$ sh sftp_with_password.sh
Connecting to user@host...
Password Authentication
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/229731/non-interactively-upload-file-to-sftp-server-using-password

Comment: Surely `<<EOF` must be on the same line as the command it attempts to interact with.

Comment: Result is same.

Comment: -bash-4.1$ sh sftp_with_password.sh
Connecting to FTP2.UPS.COM...
Password Authentication
Password:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) script could do the job.

For instance **copy-sftp.exp**:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set password [lindex $argv 0]
spawn sftp -oport=1002 user@host:/dir/archive/file*.txt /di/data/
expect "Password"
send "$password\r"
send "quit\r"
```

Then you can execute it:

```
expect copy-ftp.exp $PASSWORD
```

Comment: just add "set timeout -1" to be sure the transfer does not interrupt and there you go :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gonzalo Matheu I've managed to do a send-sftp.exp using a proxy which send a big file to a sftp :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1
set password [lindex $argv 0]
set file [lindex $argv 1]
spawn sftp -o "ProxyCommand /usr/bin/connect -H <proxy-host>:<proxy-port> %h %p" <sftp-Username>@<sftp-HOST>
expect "password:"
send "$password\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "put $file\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "quit\r"
```

Then I execute it :

```
expect send-sftp.exp $PASSWORD /PATH/TO/MYFILE.zip
```

set timeout allows the transfer not to be stoped by expect's wait timeout, you can adapt it to your needs ;)